# Anacondaのアップデートができません : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: macos, anaconda, pyenv, anaconda3

conda update conda をターミナルで実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
CondaIndexError: Invalid index file: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/tarball/master/noarch/repodata.json: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

netrcのエンコードを弄ってみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。
環境としては、Macで、Pyenvを用いてanaconda3-5.1.0で動かしています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Pyenv, Anacondaは環境変数をいじるので、この質問のように正常に動作しなくなった場合の原因をみつけるのは簡単ではありません。Pyenvの場合は、`pyenv install anaconda3-x.x.x`で新しいバージョンのAnacondaを簡単にインストールできるので、`conda update conda`でアップグレートするより、新しいバージョンのものをインストールした方がいいのではないですか。

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji  コメントありがとうございます。もともとはAnacondaを通してライブラリをインストールしようとしていたのですが、上記と同じエラー内容がでました。そこで、Anacondaをアップデートしたら治るのと考えたのですが、今回のようなエラーがでてきてしまった具合です。新しくpyenvの方でイストールしても、状況は変わりませんでした。やはり、pyenvを再インストールし直すのが良いのですかね。